# How to enable SSL with Qt QODBC

Tags: qt, ssl, odbc

I can’t find information about this. Is it possible to enable SSL with QODBC? If so, how?

I have no issues using SSL with QMySql or using non-SSL connection with QODBC.
 However, the QODBC driver documentation at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtsql/sql-driver.html#qodbc makes no mention of SSL + ODBC and QODBC rejects parameters not on the list at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtsql/qsqldatabase.html#setConnectOptions , none of which pertain to SSL.

Interestingly enough, I cannot find documentation for those options, their meanings, or their allowed values anywhere. The only mention of those options I can find at all is on that documentation page, which does not state whether it is a comprehensive list or provide any further information.

The only other direct reference I can find to using SSL with QODBC is an unanswered post from four years ago:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/34367-SSL-with-QODBC

Finding this information is further compounded by the fact that QODBC is also the name of an apparently unrelated ODBC product for Quickbooks.

This is a copy of my post at http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/36850/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass your secure connection options as part of ODBC datasource to [QSqlDatabase::setDatabaseName](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqldatabase.html#setDatabaseName). ODBC datasource should look similar to:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=server_address;Database=database;
User=username;Password=password;
sslca=ca.crt;sslcert=client.crt;sslkey=client.key;sslverify=1;
```

I haven't checked this exact string, just show the idea (taken from [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-1/)). See [MySQL Connector/ODBC documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html) for details.

Comment: It does work to put connection string syntax in the database name field of the QSqlDatabase object. It seems like a workaround or accident that some parameters (ie SSL parameters) must be manually specified via connection string syntax in the database name field and some parameters have built-in setters (`QSqlDatabase::setUserName()` etc). Other Qt SQL drivers (QMYSQL etc) do not require arbitrary connection string syntax for SSL. AFAICT this mechanism is not in the QODBC documentation.

Comment: ODBC is a generic interface and it is always better to use DB-specific drivers provided by Qt, unless they lack some required functionality. Qt [documentations for QODBC](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/sql-driver.html#qodbc) says: `Be aware that when connecting to an ODBC datasource you must pass in the name of the ODBC datasource to the QSqlDatabase::setDatabaseName() function rather than the actual database name.`

Comment: I saw that but AFAIK it refers to the name of a data source, such as in the Windows data source manager, which can be represented by a connection string but is not the same thing as a connection string. Unless I am incorrect and the connection string is implied by "name of the ODBC datasource" or the ODBC data source names and their corresponding connection strings are known to be interchangeable, the documentation does not mention this.